# In C++, is there a consensus regarding default behavior vs explicit code?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if there's any reason to explicitly write code that does the same as default behavior of C++.

Here's some code:

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseClass() {}

    virtual void f() { /* do something */ }
};

class ExplicitClass
    : public BaseClass
{
public:
    ExplicitClass()
        : BaseClass()   // <-- explicit call of base class constructor
    {
        // empty function
    }

    virtual ~ExplicitClass() {}  // <-- explicit empty virtual destructor

    virtual void f() { BaseClass::f(); }  // <-- function just calls base
};

class ImplicitClass
    : public BaseClass
{    
};
```

I'm mainly curious in the realm of refactoring and a changing code base.  I don't think many coders intend to write code like this, but it can endup looking like this when code changes over time.

Is there any point to leaving the code present in the `ExplicitClass`?  I can see the bonus that it shows you what is happening, but it comes across as lint-prone and risky.

Personally I prefer to remove any code that is default behavior code(like `ImplicitClass`).

Is there any consensus favoring one way or the other?

Comment: Consensus among C++ programmers? Surely you jest... ;-]

Comment: I believe sometimes these pieces of code that appear to not be doing anything actually do something..

Comment: Well having an explicit constructor takes away the ability to initialise the class with the `= { ... }` syntax, so that code doesn't do "nothing".

Comment: I don't think I'd go quite as far as "consensus", but I think there's a *tendency* toward believing that if it's not accomplishing something, you're better off without it -- but only remove it if you're *truly* certain it's not doing anything useful -- that's not always immediately obvious.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to this issue:

1. Define everything even if compiler generates the same,
2. Does not define anything which compile will do better.

The believers of (1) are using rules like: "Always define Default c-tor, Copy C-tor, assignment operator and d-tor".

(1) believers think it is safer to have more than to miss something. 
Unfortunately (1) is especially loved by our managers - they believe it is better to have than don't have.  Sp such rules like this "always define big four" go to "Coding standard" and must be followed.

I believe in (2). And for firms where such coding standards exist, I always put comment "Do not define copy c-tor as compiler does it better"

Answer (score 0):

As the question is about consensus, I can't answer, but I find ildjarn's comment amusing and correct.

As per your question whether there is a reason to write it like that, there is not as the explicit and implicit class behave the same. People sometimes do it for 'maintenance' reasons e.g. if derived `f` is ever implemented in a different way to remember to call the base class. I personally, don't find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Either way is fine, so long as you understand what really happens there, and the problems which may arise from not writing the functions yourself.

**EXCEPTION-SAFETY**:

The compiler will generate the functions implicitly adding the necessary `throw` conditions. For an implicitly created constructor, this would be every throw conditions from the base classes and the members.

**ILL-FORMED CODE**

There are some tricky cases where **some of the automatically generated members functions will be ill-formed.** Here is an example:

```
class Derived;

class Base
{
public:
  virtual Base& /* or Derived& */
  operator=( const Derived& ) throw( B1 );

  virtual ~Base() throw( B2 );
};

class Member
{
public:
  Member& operator=( const Member& ) throw( M1 );
  ~Member() throw( M2 );
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  Member m_;
  //   Derived& Derived::operator=( const Derived& )
  //            throw( B1, M1 ); // error, ill-formed
  //   Derived::~Derived()
  //            throw( B2, M2 ); // error, ill-formed
};
```

The `operator=` is ill-formed because its throw directive should be at least as restrictive as its base class, meaning that it should throw either B1, or nothing at all. This makes sense as a Derived object can also be seen as a Base object.

Note that it is perfectly legal to have an ill-formed function as long as you never invoke it.

I am basically rewriting GotW #69 here, so if you want more details, [you can find them here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/069.htm)

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you like to structure and read the programs. of course, there are preferences and reasons for and against each.

```
class ExplicitClass
    : public BaseClass
{
public:
```

initialization is very important. not initializing a base or member can produce warnings, rightly so or catching a bug in some cases. so this really starts to make sense if that collection of warnings is enabled, you keep the warning levels way up, and the warning counts down. it also helps to demonstrate intention:

```
    ExplicitClass()
        : BaseClass()   // <-- explicit call of base class constructor
    {
        // empty function
    }
```

an empty virtual destructor is, IME, statistically the best place to export a `virtual` (of course, that definition would be elsewhere if visible to more than one translation). you want this exported because there is a ton of rtti and vtable information that could end up as unnecessary bloat in your binary. i actually define empty destructors very regularly for this reason:

```
    virtual ~ExplicitClass() {}  // <-- explicit empty virtual destructor
```

perhaps it is a convention in your group, or it documents that this is exactly what the implementation is designed to do. this can also be helpful (subjective) in large codebases or within complex hierarchies because it can also help remind you of the dynamic interface the type is expected to adopt. some people prefer all declarations in the subclass because they can see all the class' dynamic implementation in one place. so the locality helps them in the event the class hierarchy/interface is larger than the programmer's mental stack. like the destructor, this virtual may also be a good place to export the typeinfo:

```
    virtual void f() { BaseClass::f(); }  // <-- function just calls base
};
```

of course, it gets hard to follow a program or rationale if you define only if qualified. so it can end up with some codebases easier to follow if you just stick to conventions because it is clearer than documenting why an empty destructor is exported at every turn.

a final reason (which swings both ways) is that explicit default definitions can increase and decrease build and link times.

fortunately, it's easier and unambiguous now to specify default and deleted methods and constructors.